# How to add templated selfrel to Spring HATEOAS PagedResourcesAssembler?

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

I'm currently building an API using spring hateoas. Most of my controllers provide a list method which returns a PagedResources<>. For some reason the selfrel does not contain the `{?page,size,sort}` template which is found in all examples. Instead I only get the base URI.

So my e.g. my ProjectContoller looks like

```
@GetMapping
public PagedResources<ProjectResource> list(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Project> pagedResourcesAssembler){
    Page<Project> projects = service.findAll(pageable);
    return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(projects, assembler);
}
```

and returns

```
{"_embedded":{
    "projectResourceList":[
        {
            "begin":1462053600000,
            "end":1469829600000,
            "name":"Cool Big Project",
            "_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost/projects/1"}}
        }
    ]
    },
    "_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost/projects"}},
    "page":{
        "size":20,
        "totalElements":1,
        "totalPages":1,
        "number":0
    }
}
```

I guess I'm missing something trivial but can't find out what :-/

Answer (score 0):

After reading how HAL should behave in [Spring Data Rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.prev-and-next-links) it seems there could be some bug.

This is the standard  Spring Data Rest `links` output for a `tasks` collection resource:

```
 "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=2&size=20"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/tasks"
    },
    "search": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks/search"
    }
```

No link is being templated in out of the box HAL responses rendered by Spring Data Rest, contrary to what is shown in docs.

If I follow `next` link, the `self` link is not correct:

```
"_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "prev": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=2&size=20"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=2&size=20"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/tasks"
    },
    "search": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks/search"
    }
  }
```

If I override the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/tasks")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Task>> read(Pageable pageRequest, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
        Page<Task> pendingTasks = taskService.read(pageRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity(pageAssembler.toResource(pendingTasks, (ResourceAssembler) assembler),
                                  HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And add a service between the controller and repository that initializes a `Pageable` instance to default values even if none is specified:

```
 public Page<Task> read(Pageable pageRequest) {
        Pageable effectivePageRequest = pageRequest;
        if (effectivePageRequest == null) {
            effectivePageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 20, DEFAULT_SORT);
        }
        if (effectivePageRequest.getSort() == null) {
            //override Sort
            effectivePageRequest = new PageRequest(effectivePageRequest.getPageNumber(),
                                                   effectivePageRequest.getPageSize(), DEFAULT_SORT);
        }
        return taskRepository.findByStatus(Task.Status.PENDING, effectivePageRequest);
    }
```

I can overcome the problem with the `self` link. But have seen no way of generating the templlated URIs. These are the links for the second page:

```
"_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=0&size=20&sort=created,desc"
    },
    "prev": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=0&size=20&sort=created,desc"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=1&size=20&sort=created,desc"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=2&size=20&sort=created,desc"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/tasks?page=2&size=20&sort=created,desc"
    }
```

Hope this helps discarding possibilities, but default behavior shown here suggests that there may be some problem with Spring HATEOAS/Spring Data Rest when generating collection links.

I'm using  `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE`, `org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.5.2.RELEASE`, `org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.20.0.RELEASE`

Comment: Same result, no template in the selfrel.

Comment: Does template appear when templating yourself? for example if you access `http://localhost:8080/projects?size=2`

Comment: It works fine for the first, next and last links. Those are correctly setup with the respective parameters. It's only missing the template info in the selfref :-(